# Node mysql ER_PARSE_ERROR 1064

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am inserting a row into table like this but its not working i searched on internet and tried all solutions for no luck for me i don't know what i am doing wrong here

```
var b = req.body;
mysqlConnection.query(
  'INSERT INTO `users` (`nid`, `name`, `dob`, `gender`) VALUES ?',
   [[
     b.nid,
     b.name,
     b.dob,
     b.gender
    ]],
  (error, results) => {
    if(!error)
    res.status(201).send(result.insertId);
    else
    res.send(error)
  }
```

);

**Error**

```
   "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
    "errno": 1064,
    "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '123, 'Alex', '2020-10-30', 'male' at line 1",
    "sqlState": "42000",
    "index": 0,
    "sql": "INSERT INTO `users` (`nid`, `name`, `dob`, `gender`) VALUES 123, 'Alex', '2020-10-30', 'male'"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a missing parenthesis just after `VALUES`, try this

```
mysqlConnection.query(
  'INSERT INTO `users` (`nid`, `name`, `dob`, `gender`) VALUES (?)',
   [[
     b.nid,
     b.name,
     b.dob,
     b.gender
    ]],
  (error, results) => {
    if(!error)
    res.status(201).send(result.insertId);
    else
    res.send(error)
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

[**You can see attached image and do something like that. I think you are doing bulk insert.**

```
var b = req.body;
mysqlConnection.query(
    INSERT INTO `users` (`nid`, `name`, `dob`, `gender`) VALUES ?',
        b.map(item => (item.nid, item.name, item.dob, item.gender)),
        (error, results) => {
        if(!error)
                    res.status(201).send(result.insertId);
        else
res.send(error)
```

}

]
**Attached Image:**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohqIa.png)

**And if you are not doing bulk insert then do something like below:**

```
mysqlConnection.query('INSERT INTO `users` (`nid`, `name`, `dob`, `gender`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',[b.nid,b.name,b.dob,b.gender],
 (error, results) => {
if(!error)
res.status(201).send(result.insertId);
else
res.send(error)
```

}